# Can't convert nil into string--Ruby Secret Santa

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, null

I wrote a Secret Santa program (ala Ruby Quiz...ish), but occasionally when the program runs, I get an error.
Stats: If there's 10 names in the pot, the error comes up about 5% of the time. If there's 100 names in the pot, it's less than 1%. This is on a trial of 1000 times in bash. I've determined that the gift arrays are coming up nil at some point, but I'm not sure why or how to avoid it.
Providing code...

```
0.upto($lname.length-1).each do |i|
  j = rand($giftlname.length) # should be less each time.
  while $giftlname[j] == $lname[i] # redo random if it picks same person
    if $lname[i] == $lname.last # if random gives same output again, means person is left with himself; needs to switch with someone
      $giftfname[j], $fname[i] = $giftfname[i], $fname[j]
      $giftlname[j], $lname[i] = $giftlname[i], $lname[j]
      $giftemail[j], $email[i] = $giftemail[i], $email[j]
    else
       j = rand($giftlname.length)
    end
  end
  $santas.push('Santa ' + $fname[i] + ' ' + $lname[i] + ' sends gift to ' + $giftfname[j] + ' ' + $giftlname[j] + ' at ' + '<' + $giftemail[j] + '>.') #Error here, something is sometimes nil
  $giftfname.delete_at(j)
  $giftlname.delete_at(j)
  $giftemail.delete_at(j)
end
```

Thanks SO!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using $ in front of all your variable names? In Ruby this makes them global variables, which is almost never what you want.

Comment: I originally wrote it as a new method, and it was to avoid all the variables taken in. Later on I removed the method and made it a flat program when I realized I didn't need to use recursion... but I never got around to taking out the $s.

Comment: In ruby, you should *never* need to use globals.  I'd rewrite it first thing without any $.  Part of the beauty of ruby is the lack of '$' everywhere.  (I'm not even sure why it's even supported anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
$giftfname[j], $fname[i] = $giftfname[i], $fname[j]
```

Your `i` values range between zero to the last index in `$fname` (inclusive) and, presumably, your `$giftfname` starts off as a clone of `$fname` (or at least another array with the **same length**). But, as you spin through the `each`, you're shrinking `$giftfname` so `$giftfname[i]` will be `nil` and the swap operation above will put `nil` into `$giftfname[j]` (which is supposed to be a useful entry of `$giftfname`). Similar issues apply to `$giftlname` and `$giftemail`.

I'd recommend using one array with three element objects (first name, last name, email) instead of your three parallel arrays. There's also a [`shuffle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000284) method on Array that might be of use to you:

- Start with an array of people.
- Make copy of that array.
- Shuffle the copy until it is different at every index from that original array.
- Then [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260) the together to get your final list of giver/receiver pairs.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Funny because it was an arbitrary shuffler that I stuck in for now until I designed one that worked better. Time to design a better one.

Comment: @podopie: I added an update with some hints on a better approach (for small lists at least).

Comment: I haven't gotten around to trying your solution yet, but I used a retry statement after resetting the array clones (ditching the shuffle that was there). I'm new to programming, so are retry statements acceptable in the Ruby world for clauses like this? Or is it the lazy man's way out? Thanks!

Comment: @podopie: I see `retry` as a tool to deal with unexpected or exceptional circumstances. Using `retry` for normal flow control smells a bit bad to me. IMHO of course.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and used the retry statement. the if statement now looks like this (all other variables have been edited to be non-global as well)

```
if lname[i] == lname.last 
  santas = Array.new
  giftfname = fname.clone
  giftlname = lname.clone
  giftemail = email.clone
  retry
```

That, aside from a few other edits, created the solution I needed without breaking apart the code too much again. Will definitely try out mu's solution as well, but I'm just glad I have this running error-free for now.